# Смещение рамки при трансформации Fabric.JS

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Пример тут - https://jsfiddle.net/8mjet7ov/

Не удается никак сделать, чтобы область, которая обрезается, не смещалась при трансформации объекта(изменении размера). Перейдите к примеру выше и попробуйте изменить размер объекта, там будет наглядно видно.

Код:

```
can = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var clipByName;
function drawEllipse(ctx, coords, sizes, angle) {
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.translate(coords[0], coords[1]);
    ctx.scale(1, sizes[1]/sizes[0]);
    ctx.arc(0, 0, sizes[0], 0, Math.PI*2);
}

function addImg (w,h,t,l,radius) {
    var b = can.getObjects().length;

    if (b > 0) {
        for (var i = b; i >= 0; i--) {
            removeObj(i);
        }
    }

    widths = w;
    heights = h;
    left_b = l;
    top_b = t;

    window.clipRect1 = new fabric.Ellipse({
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        left: l,
        top: t,
        rx: w,
        ry: h,
        fill: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
        selectable: false
    });

    clipRect1.set({
        clipFor: 'clip'
    });

    can.add(clipRect1);

    function findByClipName(name) {
        return _(can.getObjects()).where({
            clipFor: name
        }).first()
    }

    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    clipByName = function (ctx) {
        this.setCoords();
        var clipRect = findByClipName(this.clipName);
        var scaleXTo1 = (1 / this.scaleX);
        var scaleYTo1 = (1 / this.scaleY);
        ctx.save();

        var ctxLeft = -( this.width / 2 ) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
        var ctxTop = -( this.height / 2 ) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
        var ctxWidth = clipRect.width - clipRect.strokeWidth;
        var ctxHeight = clipRect.height - clipRect.strokeWidth;
        ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );
        console.log(this.scaleY);
        ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
            ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
            ctx.beginPath();
            drawEllipse(ctx, [(l+w) - (this.oCoords.tl.x), (t+h) - (this.oCoords.tl.y - this.scaleY)], [w, h], 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }
}

addImg(50,50,100,100,0);

var ct = new fabric.Text('TEXT', {
   left: 100,
   top: 100,
   fill: '#FFF',
   fontSize: 80,
   centeredScaling: true,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
   borderColor: 'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.60)',
   cornerColor: 'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.60)',
   cornerSize: 18,
   clipName: 'clip',
   clipTo: function(ctx) {
      return _.bind(clipByName, ct)(ctx)
   }
});
can.add(ct);
```

Comment: никто не знает?)